# Inserting quotes to pipe separated line using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a custom made tool that  parses XML files using SAX and that reproduces them into pipe separated values, an example of a line would be:

```
name|lastname|address|telephone|age|other info|other info
```

I would like to rewrite each line, i will do this using a bash script but i'm having some difficulties.
Basically i would like to set each word between quotes, an example for the above line would be:

```
"name"|"lastname"|"address"|"telephone"|"age"|"other info"|"other info"
```

i'm trying to do this using sed, and i'm partially successful with this sed line

```
sed 's:|:"|":g'
```

as i get the output:
name"|"lastname"|"address"|"telephone"|"age"|"other info"|"other info

but i dont know how to set quotes for the first char and the last char,
Any advice?

Comment: What do you do if any of the fields contain double quotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were definitely on the right track, Here's how to cover the special cases of beginning of line, end of line:

```
 sed 's:|:"|":g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/'
```

`^` char anchors search to beginning of line, the `$` char anchors search at the end of the line.

IHTH

Answer (score 3):

```
line='name|lastname|address|telephone|age|other info|other info'

echo $line| sed -e 's/|/"|"/g' -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/'
```

gives:

```
"name"|"lastname"|"address"|"telephone"|"age"|"other info"|"other info"
```

Answer (score 2):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|"; Q="\"" } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i = Q $i Q }1'
```

Results:

```
"name"|"lastname"|"address"|"telephone"|"age"|"other info"|"other info"
```

Comment: It can be a bit simpler: `{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i = Q $i Q; print}`